# P4V Get Latest does nothing

Tags: perforce, revision, p4v, getlatest

I do not want to go "Get Revision" > "Force". Because half of my stuff is already downloaded. I don't want to overwrite what I already have. P4V Can clearly see that what is in the depot and what is local is completely different. How can I get Perforce to retrieve the files I do not have, and ignore the ones I already do?

Answer (score 2):

Select your workspace root, go to File > Open Command Window Here, and run:

```
p4 clean
```

This will scan your workspace and force-sync everything that's different or missing, as well as deleting unadded files.  Note that if you have local work that isn't in a changelist, this will irrevocably erase it.  If you *only* want to "clean" files that are edited/present but out of date (and disregard added/deleted files), do `p4 clean -e` instead.  If you want to preview the operation before doing it for real, do `p4 clean -n`.

I think you can do the equivalent via the "Reconcile Offline Work" tool in P4V, but it may require additional manual steps.

To make working with Perforce easier, try to avoid modifying files in your workspace that are read-only -- if you want to remove a file from your workspace, use "remove from workspace" in P4V rather than manually deleting it, etc.  Perforce is able to make file operations very fast by virtue of knowing what's in your workspace and not having to re-check it each time, but you eliminate that benefit when you mess with your workspace manually.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `p4 clean`, you could do:

1. reconcile offline work on root of workspace then a pop-up saying that you deleted some files and it is going to delete them from Depot of the server as well make sure you added to default or new changelist or whatever. Accept.
2. Go to changelist and right-click press revert files to bring back the deleted/missing files.